# Read LocalStack SES emails via API

Tags: amazon-ses, localstack

As per [the LocalStack documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/ses/):

> The sent messages can be retrieved via a service API endpoint (GET
> /_localstack/ses) or from the filesystem.
>
> Messages are also saved to the data directory (DATA_DIR, see
> Configuration). If data directory is not available, the temporary
> directory (TMPDIR) is used. The files are saved as JSON in the ses/
> subdirectory and organised by message ID.

However, I am unable to get the "service API endpoint" method to work. The documentation is not very specific. What port is this API listening on? I've tried to cURL the default port for all localstack services (`http://localhost:4566/_localstack/ses/`), but this only returns a 404.

I have confirmed that the emails do appear in the data_dir. But I specifically want to retrieve via this API.

**EDIT**

I'm using docker-compose to start the container, but the same outcome happens when using the CLI:

```
~ localstack --version
0.14.3.3
~ SERVICES=ses localstack start -d

     __                     _______ __             __
    / /   ____  _________ _/ / ___// /_____ ______/ /__
   / /   / __ \/ ___/ __ `/ /\__ \/ __/ __ `/ ___/ //_/
  / /___/ /_/ / /__/ /_/ / /___/ / /_/ /_/ / /__/ ,<
 /_____/\____/\___/\__,_/_//____/\__/\__,_/\___/_/|_|

  LocalStack CLI 0.14.3.3

[17:02:56] starting LocalStack in Docker mode                                                                                                                                                                              localstack.py:135
[17:02:57] preparing environment                                                                                                                                                                                              bootstrap.py:729
           configuring container                                                                                                                                                                                              bootstrap.py:737
           starting container                                                                                                                                                                                                 bootstrap.py:743
[17:02:58] detaching

~ aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 ses verify-email-identity --email-address abc@mail.com
~ aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 ses send-email --destination ToAddresses=abc@test.com --message file://$HOME/tmp/message.json --from abc@mail.com
{
    "MessageId": "eorislettxoexeoc-xdcvrgnw-zggi-exmm-dfcc-dllwqdlnrrlu-thowhk"
}
~ curl -v http://localhost:4566/_localstack/ses/
*   Trying ::1:4566...
* connect to ::1 port 4566 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:4566...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4566 (#0)
> GET /_localstack/ses/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4566
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404
...
```

Comment: Can you please share the LocalStack version you are using? Try `localstack --version` and see if its the latest version. I did a cURL on `http://localhost:4566/_localstack/ses/` and received the messages I sent via SES. Thanks!

Comment: @HarshMishra, I'm starting LocalStack with docker-compose and the latest image. Then I tried using the CLI with same results. Amended post with additional information as requested.